# List of users in local security group

Tags: vb.net, windows-xp

I have a few security group under "Local USers and Groups" on a PC. Is there a way to list the users under a specific group?

I'm not sure which class to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it with the class: DirectoryEntry

Here's a quick version of the code

```
deComputer = New DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + computerName + ",computer")
deComputer.RefreshCache()

deGroup = deComputer.Children.Find(Groupname, "group")

members = deGroup.Invoke("members", Nothing)
```